# Even after putting actions handlers in 'actions' object, I still keep getting a deprecation message in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

As of recently, Emberjs got to version 1.0.0. I made a change to the controller to conform to some new changes,

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions : {
        filteredContent : function() {
            var searchText = this.get('searchText'), regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');

            return this.get('model').filter(function(item) {
                return regex.test(item.name);
            });
        }.property('searchText', 'model')
    }
});
```

This is tied to a textbox,

```
{{input type="text" value=searchText}}
```

But I still keep getting this:

```
DEPRECATION: Action handlers contained in an `events` object are deprecated in favor of putting them in an `actions` object (error on <Ember.Route:ember189>)
        at Object.triggerEvent (http://ember.local/js/libs/ember.js:30519:13)
        at trigger (http://ember.local/js/libs/ember.js:29641:16)
        at handleError (http://ember.local/js/libs/ember.js:29903:9)
        at invokeCallback (http://ember.local/js/libs/ember.js:8055:19)
        at null.<anonymous> (http://ember.local/js/libs/ember.js:8109:11)
        at EventTarget.trigger (http://ember.local/js/libs/ember.js:7878:22)
        at http://ember.local/js/libs/ember.js:8180:17
        at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (http://ember.local/js/libs/ember.js:5459:24)
        at Object.Backburner.end (http://ember.local/js/libs/ember.js:5545:27) ember.js:394
Error while loading route: 
Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
 ember.js:394
Uncaught #<Object>
```

What I might be doing wrong here?

Moreover, if anyone's interested, here's the full App.js, https://gist.github.com/ankurkaushal/55dd21838acb0dd3fb10

And here's the full HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">

            {{input type="text" value=searchText}}

            {{#each item in filteredContent }}
            <tr><td>
              {{#link-to 'user' item}} <p>{{item.name}}</p>{{/link-to}}
            </td></tr>
            {{/each}}

            {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <h1>Application Template</h1>
        {{outlet}}
</script>


     <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user">
    <h2>
        {{email}}
    </h2>

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you have `filteredContent` in a `actions` hash anyway? It's a Computed Property and thus should not be inside the `actions` hash.

Try a moving `filteredContent` outside the `actions` hash.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually the issue was, I didn't start MySQL on my machine, but why it was displaying wrong error then?

Comment: I guess because by visiting the `UsersRoute` the `model` hook tried to return the data with a call to the backend, but your backend wasn't returning anything (MySQL off) so the error occurred when `filteredContent` did get called due changes to the `model` property from the above mentioned call and then recognizing being inside a `actions` hash, this should have triggered the error.